# ActionBarCompat and windowContentOverlay

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

I've recently updated my project migrating from ActionBarSherlock to the new Google's ActionBarCompat. I've found a really tedious issue.

If you create a brand new project with ActionBarCompat (use Theme.AppCompat.Light) you'll notice that the shadow under the Action Bar is also present at the top of the window.
As I can see the default theme of Theme.AppCompat define the property windowContentOverlay as follows:

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/actionbarcompat_shadow</item>
```

I worked on it for hours but I could not resolve the problem, the shadow is duplicated on top of the ActionBar. Did anybody found the same issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a workaround posted here...  [What happened to windowContentOverlay in Android API 18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945785/what-happened-to-windowcontentoverlay-in-android-api-18)

it is also noted on that thread that this is an "official" bug and has been fixed in API 19

Comment: Link only answer are generally frowned upon here, due to the fact that if the link gets brought down, so will your answer. Please show us an example here of what you mean.

Comment: maybe i should have just marked the question as a possible repeat???  the answer i linked to is on stack overflow, and i'm fairly sure that "it's a bug unique to API 18 but fixed in API 19" doesn't really have code to go with it