# Override library styles for activity

Tags: android, android-manifest

I use SDK in my project with certain styles for activities, for ex

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    ...
</style>
```

Manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name="im.pack.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

I want to make windowActionBarOverlay false in my new project's MainActivity, which will use SDK, but without creating new class that extends sdk's MainActivity.

Is it possible to override styles in other way?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want to have an activity whose style has item `windowActionBarOverlay` set to false?

Comment: Can't you just define a custom theme and assign it to your activity? I don't actually get the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell which version of android API are you using?

Please, check this answer:

[What happened to windowContentOverlay in Android API 18?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945785/what-happened-to-windowcontentoverlay-in-android-api-18)

Did you try to add this string into your manifest file?

```
<application android:theme="@style/Theme.Foo">
```